# not running in simulator (libGoogleConversionTracking.a)

Tags: ios, swift

can you please help me? In my project, I am using libGoogleConversionTracking.after update Xcode(Xcode 14.2) facing this issue.Working perfectly on a device but facing this issue in the simulator.
Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file Pods/GoogleConversionTracking/Libraries/libGoogleConversionTracking.a' for architecture arm64

Note - Already try to add arm64 in excluded architecture but not working